# How to add write permission to a group?

Tags: permissions, samba, groups

How can I give write permission to a group?

The problem is: when somebody creates a file in the folder, the others in the same group can't modify it. I tried `chmod`, but the newly created files had *read only* permission.

Comment: So you want the directory permissions to be automatically applied on new files? If so, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580584/setting-default-permissions-for-newly-created-files-and-sub-directories-under-a

Comment: i tried 'chmod g+rwxs dirname' and the old files got the w, but the new ones are all only readable

Comment: Try the answer below ([ACL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs))

Comment: Resorting to ACLs shouldn't be necessary for this should it?

Comment: solved it!
i had to set the acl first.
sudo setfacl -d -m g:group folder